# Dealing with rsyslog. rsyslog issue

Tags: debian, snmp, rsyslog

I'm trying to execute this 3 commands into rsyslog:

```
IFS=':' read -a trap <<< "${msg}" 
IFS='#' read -a trap2 <<< "${trap[11]}" 
if $trap2 > 300 then ^/pruebas/script.sh
```

But when I restart rsyslog I got errors like this:

```
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started. 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="12495" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ] 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 22:" IFS=':' read -a trap <<< "${msg}"" 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name "" [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/3000 ] 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 24:" IFS='#' read -a trap2 <<< "${trap[11]}"" 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd: warning: selector line without actions will be discarded 
Aug 11 13:05:49 sSAI rsyslogd-2124: CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [try rsyslog... ]
```

I got the same message with every different code I put into rsyslog.

My goal is to identify a part of a snmp trap. I am receiving traps and extracting that value, and when that value is bigger than 300, execute a shell script.

Any ideas? Thanks.